# Convergence in Probability for sum of $X_i^2$

Tags: probability, inequality, convergence-divergence

> [image]

So I know that I have to find $\textbf{E}[Y_n]$ and $\text{var}(Y_n)$ and then use Chebyshev's inequality to prove this question, but I'm having trouble deriving $\textbf{E}(Y_n)$ and $\text{var}(Y_n)$. I think I got $\textbf{E}(Y_n)$, 
which is $$ \textbf{E}(X_i^2) = \text{var}(X_i) + (\textbf{E}(X_i))^2.$$

Hopefully this is correct. I do not know how to get $\text{var}(Y_n)$ after this though as it requires finding $\textbf{E}(Y_n^2)$.

I think end result should look something like 
$$P(|Y_n-\textbf{E}(Y_n)|>\epsilon) < \frac{\text{var}(Y_n)}{\epsilon^2}.$$

And then obviously I would write $\textbf{E}(Y_n)$ and $\text{var}(Y_n)$ in terms of $\textbf{E}(X_1)$ and $\text{var}(X_1)$ as I am asked to do so in the question, and finally prove that the right hand side = $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Hint: For $var(Y_n)$ use the facts that functions of IID random variables are still IID random variables **and** if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables then we have $var(X+Y)=var(X)+var(Y)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the easiest approach

We want to apply the strong law, which says that for i.i.d. $\xi_n$, $\frac{1}{n}\sum \xi_n \rightarrow E\xi_1$ a.s. as long as $E|\xi_1| < \infty$. Now let $\xi_n = X_n^2$, we can apply the law of large numbers as long as$EX_1^2 < \infty$. However, we know that $\text{Var}(X_1) = EX_1^2 - (EX_1)^2$ and therefore $EX_1^2 = \text{Var}(X_1) + (EX_1)^2 < \infty$ and we can apply the law of large numbers to see that $\frac{1}{n} \sum X_n^2 \rightarrow EX_1^2$ a.s., but we already know the that $EX_1^2 = \text{Var}(X_1) + (EX_1)^2$ and we are done

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you made use of the *linearity of expectation*:

$\begin{align}\mathsf {E}(Y_n) ~&=~ \mathsf {E}(\sum_{j=1}^n\tfrac 1nX_j^2) \\[1ex] ~&=~ \tfrac 1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathsf {E}(X_i^2)\end{align}$

Then you called upon the identical distribution of the $X_i$, and the definition of variance:

$\begin{align}\mathsf {E}(Y_n) ~&=~ \mathsf {E}(X_1^2) \\[1ex] &=~ \mathsf {Var}(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_1)^2\end{align}$

---

Now using *mostly* the same approach, we can apply the *bilinearity of covariance*:

$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(Y_n) ~&=~ \mathsf {Cov}(\sum_{j=1}^n\tfrac 1nX_j^2,\sum_{k=1}^n\tfrac 1nX_k^2) \\[1ex] ~&=~ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathsf {Var}(
\tfrac 1nX_i^2)+\underset{1\leq j<k\leq n}{2\sum}\!\mathsf {Cov}(\tfrac 1n X_j^2,\tfrac 1nX_k^2)\end{align}$

And of course, since the random variables are *independent*, as well as *identically distributed*, this is simplified:

$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(Y_n) ~&=~ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathsf {Var}(
\tfrac 1nX_i^2) \\[1ex] & =~ \tfrac 1n\mathsf {Var}(X_1^2)\end{align}$

*That* however, will *not* be obtainable in terms of $\mathsf E(X_1)$, $\mathsf{Var}(X_1)$.   Though you should be able to make claims about the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I think you mean that $E[Y_n]=E[X_1^2]=Var[X_1]+E[X_1]^2$

Comment: Cool. I see that since the variance of Yn is a fraction over n, the limit as n approaches infinity should then be 0. I think this is enough to answer the question.

Comment: @Adam Since $\text{Var} (X_1^2)$ depends on the fourth moment of $X_1$ one cannot say that $\text{Var} (X_1^2)$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

For evaluating $var(Y_n)$ refer my comment in the question or refer the other answer.

I write this answer to prove that $Y_n \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} E(Y_n)$ only with the hypothesis that $E(X_i^2)$ is finite. The proof by Chebyshev inequality uses the fact that $\text{Var} (X_1^2) < \infty$ which is not true in general and by the given hypothesis. So following is the proof using the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)).

By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) for [complex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex-valued_function), the characteristic function of any random variable, $V$, with finite mean $\mu$, can be written as:

$\varphi_V(t) = 1 + it\mu + o(t), \quad t \rightarrow 0.$

All $X_1^2,X_2^2,\cdots$ have the same characteristic function, so we will simply denote this by $\varphi_V$.

Among the basic properties of characteristic functions there are:
$\varphi_{\frac 1 n X}(t)= \varphi_X(\tfrac t n) \quad \text{and} \quad
 \varphi_{X+Y}(t)=\varphi_X(t) \varphi_Y(t) \quad $ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

These rules can be used to calculate the characteristic function of $Y_n$ in terms of $\varphi_V$:

$\varphi_{Y_n}(t)= \left[\varphi_V\left({t \over n}\right)\right]^n = \left[1 + i\mu{t \over n} + o\left({t \over n}\right)\right]^n \, \rightarrow \, e^{it\mu}, \quad \text{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty.$

The limit $e^{it\mu}$ is the characteristic function of the constant random variable $\mu$, and hence by the [Lévy continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem), $ Y_n$ converges in distribution to $\mu$.

Since $\mu$ is a constant, convergence in distribution to $\mu$ and convergence in probability to $\mu$ are equivalent.

Therefore, $Y_n \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} E(Y_n)$ whenever $E(X_i^2)$ is finite.

And $E(Y_n) = E(X_1^2) = var(X_1) + (E(X_1))^2.$

Comment: Thank you. The question assumes that both var(x) and E(x) are finite, so E(x^2) I would assume must be finite as it is the addition of var(x) and (E(x))^2, two finite numbers.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes and thus this proof is a valid one since it uses finiteness of only $E(X^2)$ and not of $E(X^4)$ which is essential when Chebyshev's inequality is used.

Comment: Why don't just use strong law of large numbers, which holds as long as each element of the sequence is integrable?

Comment: @Ran Wang: Yes. Strong law of large numbers is applicable. I just wanted to *complete* the proof without the use of SLLN directly.